# showing different web application in one root application

Tags: java, jsp, iframe

Suppose, in root.com website's header there are 3 links called A,B and C.If we click on those links we are getting redirected to A.com,B.com and C.com.I need to show them within root.com with those links are visible above. How can I achieve this please if they are in same domain?

Comment: you want something like root.com/A etc or a.root.com etc?

Comment: Hi!root.com will stay as it is.In its body others will open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iframe to load A.com, B.com and C.com

On click of hyperlink use a java script function which set the src of iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks!!,how can I make it work if I am working with cross browser env(mobile also) and also if the child sites call any third party API or redirects to another site from within IFrame will that create any problem?

Comment: It depends on what implementation you have given in your child sites. But in my opinion it should not create any problem. :-)

Comment: Hi Ankit!    <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
was not working.So as yahoo.com.I found both google.com and yahoo.com have **X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN**.But it worked with others.Thanks.